# PDO throwing error if MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND is used

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND seem to break down the query, try your own.

The following:

```
  $connection = new \PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_orm_test", "dev", "dev",[
     PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES UTF8; SET CHARACTER SET UTF8; SET character_set_connection=UTF8; SET character_set_client=UTF8;"
  ]);
  $statement = $connection->prepare("describe users");
  $statement->execute();
  $statement->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  var_dump($statement->errorInfo());
  $statement->closeCursor();
```

Throws:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "00000"
  [1]=>
  int(2014)
  [2]=>
  string(269) "Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active.  Consider using PDOStatement::fetchAll().  Alternatively, if your code is only ever going to run against mysql, you may enable query buffering by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute."
}
```

If I remove the MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND everything works fine instead... any idea?

Notice that not even this does work...

```
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => self::DRIVER_INIT,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true
```

Comment: Do you mean "SET NAMES UTF8; SET CHARACTER SET UTF8; SET character_set_connection=UTF8; SET character_set_client=UTF8;" queries? To be able to use utf8 encoding <for real> without modifying the mysql.cnf. Thanks anyway!

Comment: As a side note, you may want utf8mb4 instead of utf8. See https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using PHP >= 5.3.6, so add charset to dsn and don't use `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`. Further I think you can only execute 1 query with `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND`. That might be the problem.

```
mysql:host=localhost;dbname=php_orm_test;charset=utf8
```

Comment: Well, this does not explain why the init command cause the bug but is a way to avoid that command, have the utf8 again and keep on working!

Comment: Just 1 query? Pretty stupid I guess... do you have a link where you found this? Thanks red!!!

Comment: [here](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/0978f443vg/48859-new-pdo-mysql-does-not-support-multiple-inital-queries) is a bug report. don't know if it's fixed in new PHP versions. But it looks like it's not.

Comment: yeah there it is! just one query allowed within the mysql init attr... thanks again redreggae.

Answer (score 5):

You can at least use multiple `SET` statements delimited by commas, e.g. `SET names utf8, @@session.sql_mode = '';`