# PHPMyAdmin: how to change timezone to Europe/London

Tags: php, datetime, phpmyadmin, timezone, timestamp

I'm using PHPMyAdmin to store my blog posts in a database. It works fine but I have a problem with the time zone.

The date is stored as "current timestamp on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" but it's showing the date and timezone from the US.

I already changed my php.ini file (advise from Bluehost) by replacing "date.timezone = "America/Denver"; with "date.timezone = "Europe/London"; but that didn't change anything.

What should I do to display the correct timezone?

**EDIT:**

I tried to set the time zone right after connecting to my database like someone suggested in the comments but it gives me an error.

How do I add `SET time_zone = 'Europe/London'` correctly to the following code:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8'));
```

I changed the above code into the code below but apparently that's not the right way to do this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8', 'SET time_zone = 'Europe/London''));
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: You need to change timezone in MySQL. If your host won't allow you to change this, you need to execute this query, right after you connect to MySQL: `SET time_zone = "+3:00"`. MySQL docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html

Comment: I tried to do that but it gives me an error. How do I add `SET time_zone = ..."`correctly with the following code: `$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exampletable', 'exampleuser', 'examplepassw', array(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND =>  'SET NAMES utf8', 'SET time_zone = 'Europe/London''));`

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17891372/1294631 you're only allowed to execute one query (according to your PHP version). You might have to manually execute it right after connecting to your database.